# 'Object is possibly Undefined' error on a non-object variable in React-Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I found the 5-6 other questions I actually kinda fixed it with " ! " operator, so don't delete the question for duplication, but what I don't understand is the variable is not an object. So this is the context;

```
import { createContext } from "react";

interface PlanetInfos {
  planetName: string;
  radius: string;
  distanceFromSun?: string;
  numberOfMoons?: string;
  averageTemperature: string;
  svg: string;
}

type ContextProps = {
  miliSeconds: number;
  setmiliSeconds: any;
  planetInfos: PlanetInfos[];
};

const PlanetContext = createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});

export default PlanetContext;
```

here is the App.js where I define the miliseconds for example;

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [miliSeconds, setmiliSeconds] = useState(10000);

  return (
    <PlanetContext.Provider
      value={{
        miliSeconds,
        setmiliSeconds,
        planetInfos,
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <SideBar />
        <Planets />
      </div>
    </PlanetContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

So in wherever I do this and use miliseconds somewhere in the component;

```
const { miliSeconds } = useContext(PlanetContext);
```

It says "Object is possibly undefined" and it doesn't make sense for me. Because it was never an object. So is there any solution besides putting exclamation mark everywhere in the app?

Comment: It is because you used partial : Partial<ContextProps>. Partials makes everything "optional"  = the type you mentioned or "undefined"

Comment: @AjeetShah It's just imported to App.tsx from somewhere else, but that doesn't really matter

Comment: If none of the properties is supposed to be "undefiend", you don't need to use Partial, you can write : `createContext<ContextProps>({} as ContextProps) ;` or perhaps `createContext({} as ContextProps) ;`

Comment: And you can improve : `setmiliSeconds: (ms: number) => void `

Comment: oh man thanks, this kinda resolved everything. just couldn't get the ms stuff in the parameter though

Comment: Did you met an error when defining typings for setmiliSeconds as I wrote in comment above? Actually, you can improve that further by adding a type for "updater" function as well (but maybe you won't need in this example).

Comment: no, I change the createContext as you said and didn't get any errors. I removed the partial

Answer (score 2):

```
 createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});
```

I think this code leads to define the type of the context not equals to ContextProps, but all object fields will be possibly undefined. Partial util type does this. Then, even if you define values for the context in App component before using it, typescript knows nothing about this, and infer a type of milliseconds as one from Partical, so it will be `number | undefined`